# How does a blur gauss algorithm look like? Are there examples of implementation?

Tags: c++, algorithm, image-processing, gaussian

I have a bitmap image context and want to let this appear blurry. So best thing I can think of is a gauss algorithm, but I have no big idea about how this kind of gauss blur algorithms look like? Do you know good tutorials or examples on this? The language does not matter so much, if it's done all by hand without using language-specific API too much. I.e. in cocoa the lucky guys don't need to think about it, they just use a Imagefilter that's already there. But I don't have something like this in cocoa-touch (objective-c, iPhone OS).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually quite simple. You have a filter pattern (also known as filter kernel) - a (small) rectangular array with coefficients - and just calculate the [convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) of the image and the pattern.

```
for y = 1 to ImageHeight
  for x = 1 to ImageWidth
    newValue = 0
    for j = 1 to PatternHeight
      for i = 1 to PatternWidth
        newValue += OldImage[x-PatternWidth/2+i,y-PatternHeight/2+j] * Pattern[i,j]
    NewImage[x,y] = newValue
```

The pattern is just a Gauss curve in two dimensions or any other filter pattern you like. You have to take care at the edges of the image because the filter pattern will be partialy outside of the image. You can just assume that this pixels are balck, or use a mirrored version of the image, or what ever seems reasonable.

As a final note, there are faster ways to calculate a convolution using Fourier transforms but this simple version should be sufficent for a first test.

Comment: I am following this example, but I access my pixel image in the following way: `pImg[i*iWidth+j] = currentPixel` where `i` and `j` are variables from a nested for-loop. How would I then change the line `newValue += OldImage[x-PatternWidth/2+i, y-PatternHeight/2+j] * Pattern[i,j]` and `NewImage[x,y] = newValue` using the way I read the pixel?

Answer (score 1):

The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur) has a sample matrix in addition to some standard information on the subject.

Comment: Is there a way of porting this 7*7 matrix into the 4*4 matrix of cocoa-touch CALayer transform matrix?

Comment: No.  A transform matrix is for doing coordinate transformations (translate, rotate, etc).  It has no relation to a convolution matrix (used to mix pixel values together).

Answer (score 1):

Best place for image processing is [**THIS**](http://www.imageprocessingplace.com/). You can get matlab codes there.
And [**this Wolfram demo**](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/GaussianSmoothing/) should clear any doubts about doing it by hand.

And if you don't want to learn too many things learn [PIL(Python Imaging Library)](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/).

"**[Here](http://www.riisen.dk/dop/pil.html)**" is exactly what you need.

Code copied from above link:

```
import ImageFilter

def filterBlur(im):

    im1 = im.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR)

    im1.save("BLUR" + ext)

filterBlur(im1)
```

Comment: does the PIL really run on the iPhone? (I don't have an iPhone, I'm just curious)

Comment: I don't know. I don't have iPhone either. :-D

Comment: iPhone is objective-c. I'm not sure about that python stuff, but i'd say no it doesn't run there. Correct me if I'm wrong.